# Best match location data - two tables

Tags: pandas, matlab, join, datatable, match

I have searched a lot on matching location data (long+lat) but without an answer.

I have location data (longitude and latitude) for certain sites and I want to compare these two with a national database to know the local authority of these sites + their postcodes.
I have two tables:

| Site name | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14182-Pembroke Refinery | 51.686081 | -5.0271217 |
| 8059-New Rugby | 52.376283 | -1.2860374 |
| 8037-Ketton | 52.636537 | - -0.54737666 |

And

| Postcode | Local authority | long | lat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CV21 2RY | Rugby | -1.288555 | 52.376856 |
| TR26 2JQ | Cornwall | -5.490944 | 50.207428 |
| SY10 7RN | Shropshire | -3.067703 | 52.917641 |
| SA71 5SJ | Pembrokeshire | -5.02713 | 51.686093 |
| PE9 3SX | Rutland | -0.5462 | 52.636828 |

By best matching both the latitude and longitude data from the first table with the second, the postcode and local authority will be known.

please note that the longitude and latitude are NOT exactly matched but will differ slightly hence I want the best match possible based on both info.

The new table should return:

| Site name | local authority | Postcode | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I appreciate your help with this.
Many thanks

Comment: Please let in your question a code sample of the dataframe used.

Comment: I dont think you can do it only with these two tables because some cites may be closer to another county's local authorities than the one they actually belong to.  Inter counties frontiers are not circles. However you can use some additional data like from the UK-Towns-Sample (https://www.townslist.co.uk/) which provides features such as name, county, latitude, longitude, postcode_sector, and local_government_area. This kind of data will help you. Free sample has 1800 examples. You need to google more for other data from gov.uk